# I couldn't make HTMX work with Bun because I had a issue with importing

Tags: typescript, htmx, sortablejs, bun

Installed via

```
bun add htmx.org
bun add v1.0.1 (31aec4eb)

 installed htmx.org@1.9.5


 1 packages installed [2.40s]
```

Imported with `import "htmx.org";`

Used it in

```
htmx.onLoad(function(content) {
    var sortables = content.querySelectorAll(".sortable");
    for (var i = 0; i < sortables.length; i++) {
      var sortable = sortables[i];
      new Sortable(sortable, {
          animation: 150,
          ghostClass: 'blue-background-class'
      });
    }
})
```

Got the error `Cannot find name 'htmx'.ts(2304)`

I was trying to use sortableJS but, when I was importing HTMX I got no HTMX found error.

Thanks for helping up front.

Comment: Please share your complete bun file

Comment: You miss all specifics here, so I agree: show more code and how you execute it. Some early assumption: bun is JS runtime for backend and htmx is frontent (client-side) library.